# My code pulls up a blank page after inserting values

Tags: python, html, css, forms, bottle

I'm running code in Bubble and the inputting values page works just fine but when I hit the submit button that supposed to use a method, "post", to use the second html file to show a result the page just goes blank. The website that runs my code is http://sambilli.pythonanywhere.com/final so if using that will help there it is. (Code Below with file names below each part.) (just a note that I am currently working on the bottom if statements and have only completed (character == 1) and (character == 2)

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Genshin Calculator</title>
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
      }
  
      h1 {
        text-align: center;
        color: #333;
      }

      form {
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
      }
 
      label {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
      }
  
      select {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: none;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      button[type="submit"] {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 20px;
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      button[type="submit"]:hover {
        background-color: #555;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Genshin Impact Calculator</h1>
    <form action="/damage_results" method="post">
      <fieldset>
        <label>Character:</label>
        <select name="character">
          <option value="0">Hu tao(Pyro)</option>
          <option value="1" selected>Xiangling(Pyro)</option>
          <option value="2">Xiao(Anemo)</option>
          <option value="3">Raiden Shogun(Electro)</option>
        </select>

        <label>Weapon:</label>
        <select name="weapon">
          <option value="0" selected>Catch</option>
          <option value="1">Staff of Homa</option>
          <option value="2">Deathmatch</option>
          <option value="3">Staff of Scarlet Sands</option>
        </select>

        <label>Reactions(Pyro Characters Only):</label>
        <select name="reaction">
          <option value="0" selected>None</option>
          <option value="1">Vaporize</option>
          <option value="2">Melt</option>
        </select>
      </fieldset>

      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body> 
</html>
```

^indexfinal.html

---

```
<%
from bottle import request

character = request.forms.get("character")
character = int(character)

weapon = request.forms.get("weapon")
weapon = int(weapon)

reaction = request.forms.get("reaction")
reaction = int(reaction)

weaponBaseAttack = (454.36, 509.61, 564.78, 620.03, 541.83, 608.07, 674.33, 740.58)
#arrays of each different weapon types that contain the possible weapon options
weaponList = ("catch", "homa", "deathmatch", "soss")
#set of arrays that has each characters base stats
characterNames = ("hu tao", "xiangling", "xiao", "raiden")
characterBA = (106.43, 225.14, 349.2, 337.24)
characterHP = (15552, 10875, 12736, 12907)
characterDEF = (876.15, 668.87, 799.30, 789.31)
characterEM = (0, 96, 0, 0)
characterCR = (.05, .05, .242, .05)
characterCD = (.884, .50, .50, .50)
characterER = (0, 0, 0, .32)
characterBD = (0, 0, 0, 0)

if(reaction == 1):
    reactionDMGbonus = 1.5 * (1 + (2.78 * EM)/(1400 + EM))
elif(reaction == 2):
    reactionDMGbonus = 2 * (1 + (2.78 * EM)/(1400 + EM))
else:
    reactionDMGbonus = 1

BA = characterBA[character]
HP = characterHP[character]
DEF = characterDEF[character]
EM = characterEM[character]
CR = characterCR[character]
CD = characterCD[character]
ER = characterER[character]
atkP = 0
atkP = float(atkP)
ATK = 311
ATK = float(ATK)
bonusDMG = float(characterBD[character]) + 1
#Converts all characters base values to floats (part of setBaseStats)
BA = float(BA)
HP = float(HP)
DEF = float(DEF)
ER = float(ER)
EM = float(EM)
CR = float(CR)
CD = float(CD)
ER = float(ER)

if(weapon == 0):
    #catch
    ER = ER + .459
    BA = BA + weaponBaseAttack[1]
    CR = CR + .311
elif(weapon == 1):
    #homa
    CD = CD + .662
    BA = BA + weaponBaseAttack[5]
    CR = CR + .311
    maxHP = (HP * .20) + HP + 4780
    if(character != 0):
        ATK = (.018 * maxHP) + ATK
elif(weapon == 2):
    #deathmatch
    CR = CR + .368
    BA = BA + weaponBaseAttack[0]
    CD = CD + .662
    atkP = atkP = .32
elif(weapon == 3):
    #soss
    CR = CR + .441
    BA = BA + weaponBaseAttack[4]
    CD = CD + .662
    ATK = (.52 * EM)

if(character == 1):
    #xiangling
    baseEnemyResistance = .1
    baseEnemyResistance = float(baseEnemyResistance)
    atkP = atkP + 46.6
    ATK = ATK + BA * (1 + atkP)
    ATK = float(ATK)
    enemyResistance = 1 - baseEnemyResistance
    formulaDMG = ATK * bonusDMG * (CR * CD + 1) * .5 * enemyResistance
    DMG = 2.016 * formulaDMG * reactionDMGbonus
elif(character == 0):
    #hutao
    baseEnemyResistance = .1
    baseEnemyResistance = float(baseEnemyResistance)
    formulaDMG = ATK * bonusDMG * (CR * CD + 1) * .5 * enemyResistance
elif(character == 2):
    #xiao
    atkP = atkP + 46.6
    ATK = ATK + BA * (1 + atkP)
    ATK = float(ATK)
    baseEnemyResistance = .1
    baseEnemyResistance = float(baseEnemyResistance)
    enemyResistance = 1 - baseEnemyResistance
    bonusDMG = bonusDMG + .952 + .466 + .15
    formulaDMG = ATK * bonusDMG * (CR * CD + 1) * .5 * enemyResistance
    DMG = 4.04 * formulaDMG
elif(character == 3):
    #raiden
    atkP = atkP + 46.6
    ATK = ATK + BA * (1 + atkP)
    ATK = float(ATK)
    baseEnemyResistance = .1
    baseEnemyResistance = float(baseEnemyResistance)
    enemyResistance = 1 - baseEnemyResistance
    formulaDMG = ATK * bonusDMG * (CR * CD + 1) * .5 * enemyResistance


end
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Genshin Calculator - Results</title>
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      color: #333;
    }

    p {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #555;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Genshin Impact Calculator - Results</h1>
  <p>Your High Plunge Damage is {{DMG}}.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

^resultsfinal.html

---

from bottle import default_app, route, post, template

```
@route('/form')
def index():
    return template('index.html')

@post('/result')
def calculate_bmi():
    return template('calculate_bmi.html')

@route('/formbb')
def indexbb():
    return template('indexbb.html')

@post('/resultbb')
def calculate_bmibb():
    return template('calculate_bmibb.html')

@route('/final')
def indexfinal():
    return template('indexfinal.html')

@post('/damage_results')
def resultsfinal():
    return template('resultsfinal.html')

application = default_app()
```

^bottle_app.py

Thank You for the help and I hope that the program gets up and running.

I was expecting literately anything to appear on the page at least a title. but it seems the program doesn't even get to the use of my html code.

Comment: Why not minimize the problem? Start with nothing in the file except "hello world" and add code back line by line until you're able to reproduce the problem. Whatever that last line you added was the issue. You can do the same thing by adding print statements line by line until you figure out where it's failing. Also, check your server logs for errors. See [mcve] for more on how to debug programs.